# Exchangelib: ErrorIrresolvableConflict while modifying Email

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I had to use exchangelib, to modify the subject of some of my emails.
The following is the line of code that I am using to modify the email subjects.
I am using App details with the exchangelib package.

```
credentials = OAuth2Credentials(client_id="", client_secret="",
                                            tenant_id="",
                                            identity=Identity(primary_smtp_address=""))

config = Configuration(credentials=credentials, auth_type=OAUTH2,
                                        service_endpoint='https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/exchange.asmx')

    account = Account(
        primary_smtp_address=mailbox_name,
        config=config,
        access_type=IMPERSONATION)
    inbox = account.inbox
    if inbox.all().exists():
        for message in inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:10]:
            message.subject = "Modified Subject"
            # message.save()
            message.save(update_fields=['subject'])
```

The update message operation is throwing the below error:

```
message.save(update_fields=['subject'])


File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\items\item.py", line 97, in save
    item_id, changekey = self._update(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\util.py", line 38, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\items\item.py", line 183, in _update
    res = UpdateItem(account=self.account).get(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 93, in get
    res = list(self.call(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 550, in _pool_requests
    for elem in self._get_elements(payload=payload_func(chunk, **kwargs)):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 118, in _get_elements
    for i in self._response_generator(payload=payload):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 414, in _get_elements_in_response
    container_or_exc = self._get_element_container(message=msg, name=self.element_container_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 373, in _get_element_container
    raise self._get_exception(code=response_code, text=msg_text, msg_xml=msg_xml)
exchangelib.errors.ErrorIrresolvableConflict: The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item.
```

Comment: Also asked in the issue tracker: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/858